# Item in a sub-menu disappearing in mobile view in Semantic-UI

Tags: semantic-ui

Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/797311vt/.

The following menu looks fine in broader views but the last item (fourth) dissapears in mobile view. It also dissapears with `<div class="right stackable menu">`.

```
<div class="ui stackable menu">
  <a href="#" class="item">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Second</a>
  <div class="right menu">
    <a href="#" class="item">Third</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Fourth</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I make a stackable menu where all four items show in mobile view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open bug as of 22-Sep,2016 (link: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3604 )

To move around the bug, you can do the following: https://jsfiddle.net/batrasoe/udpzkj7p/

```
<div class="ui stackable menu">
  <a href="#" class="item">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Second</a>   
   <a href="#" class="right item">Third</a>  
   <a href="#" class="item" id="last-item">Fourth</a>

  </div>
```

It does not use a right menu, but assigns the right class to the second-last element in the menu, which pushes the right of the elements to the right.

You would also have to add a border-left property to the last element. See fiddle for details.